# Images on home page moving. Repositions on load

Tags: html, image, css

so I'm working on this site http://www.burdhousestudios.com/ and the images don't set how they should be. They look fine when dropped into the browser from my text editor, but not when they're first loaded on the website. They load fine after you click the 'home' link tho. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean they "don't set how they should be". How should they be setting and what are they doing instead?

Comment: Where to begin.. Look, you must tell us WHAT is happening and WHAT you want and you must SHOW us how It's done.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are not fully loaded when your script is running for the first time.
Take a look at this question/answer [Wait for image to be loaded before going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645143/wait-for-image-to-be-loaded-before-going-on)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made some mistake in script. For the first time the page loads all your image width is 0. I checked with Inspect Element, there it is showing the width as 0. But when u click on the home page it is showing width as 250. Check your script.