# Load images using jQuery Deferred and store them in an image repository

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load, repository

Searching for answers I found this thread using jQuery Deferred for loading several images and waiting before going on:

[Wait for image to be loaded before going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645143/wait-for-image-to-be-loaded-before-going-on).

I'd like to implement this in my code but there's a point I didn't understand yet. In which context or scope can I use these image objects. Or how can I adapt the answer of the thread above in order to provide these images in an *image repository*.

In detail (as in the thread above):

```
var imagesLoaded = false;

var imageRepository = new function() {

    function loadSprite(src) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var sprite = new Image();
        sprite.onload = function() {
            deferred.resolve();
        };
        sprite.src = src;
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    var loaders = [];

    loaders.push(loadSprite('1.png'));
    loaders.push(loadSprite('2.png'));
    loaders.push(loadSprite('3.png'));

    $.when.apply(null, loaders).done(function() {
        imagesLoaded = true;
    });

}
```

Are the images (sprites) created with *new* in the function loadSprite() accessible in imageRepository, e.g., like imageRepository.sprite1?

My idea was doing something like

```
var imageRepository = new function() {

    ...

    this.sprite1 = loadSprite('1.png');

}
```

But loadSprite() returns the deferred promise object.

Am I totally wrong with this idea?