# dynamic image variable with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several canvases. I also have several picture URLs. I want to draw all pictures on the canvas. There is a problem in the drawing function. Drawing the image only works when the image loads completely, but I have to draw the image as it loads. I wrote following code:

```
for (var i = 2; i < length; i++) {
    canvid[i] = "canv" + i;
    img[i] = new Image();

    img[i].src = "..\\images\\UploadImage\\"+ name + i + ".jpg";

    img[i].onload = function () { 
        var c = document.getElementById(canvId[i]);
        var cDraw = c.getContext("2d");
        cDraw.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0);
    };
```

I know this code has error, it's kind of pseudo code to show what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is in following link

[stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645143/wait-for-image-to-be-loaded-before-going-on)

when you want to call on click event on image  variable you have to wait for it 
so you couldn't use loop you have to put next call on previous image on load event .

```
 var loadImages = function (imageURLarray) {
                if (!(startPage < pages))
                    return;
                canvid = "canv" + i;
                img.src = imageURLarray[startPage];
                // your top code
                img.onload = function (e) {
                    // code, run after image load
                    var c = document.getElementById(canvid);
                    var cDraw = c.getContext("2d");
                    cDraw.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    startPage++;
                    loadImages(imageURLarray);
                }
            }

            loadImages(imageURLarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic in

```
$(documet).ready(function(){

   //logic
});
```