# In javascript, redirect page which sends data to the server before transitioning to a new page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a redirect page which sends data to the server before transitioning to a new page, with javascript like following code.

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

****
light transaction about cookie
****

document.createElement("img").setAttribute("src", "server.php?param1=cookiedata");

location.href = "new_page.html";

</script>

</body>
```

However, before redirecting to "new_page.html", sometimes

```
document.createElement("img").setAttribute("src","server.php?param1=cookiedata");
```

is not called, and cannot send a data to "server.php".

Is it a problem that the redirect time is short?

Could you tell me how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that sometimes the request to load the source material for the is not sent before the redirection happens.

The solution is simple: You can use the [`onload`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event to add a handler which is called after the `img` has been loaded.

so something like this

```
function refirectAfterTransmit() {
  window.location.href = "/new_page.html";
}

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.addEventListener("load", refirectAfterTransmit);
img.src = "server.php?param1=cookiedata";
document.appendChild(img)
```

Let me know if this helps!

edit: thanks [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) for comments

Comment: `.setAttribute("onload", refirectAfterTransmit);` that's not valid javascript!

Comment: thus, I said "something like this", more of a pseudocode thing going on there

Comment: fair enough ... I've never thought of using pseudocode as an answer :p

Comment: I'd use `img.src =` and `img.addEventListener('load', ...` myself :p

Comment: that would make for a more beautiful solution, yes

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:
[Wait for image to be loaded before going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645143/wait-for-image-to-be-loaded-before-going-on)

you might want to wait for the "image" to be loaded. then you are sure the request has been sent.

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

****
light transaction about cookie
****

function loadSprite(src, callback) {
    var sprite = new Image();
    sprite.onload = callback;
    sprite.src = src;
}


loadSprite('server.php?param1=cookiedata', function() {
    location.href = "new_page.html";
});



</script>

</body>
```