# Javascript wait for uploading image

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below code I have 3 `alert()` and I want to these alerts respectively fired. first `alert(1)`, second `alert(2)` and then `alert(3)` but now because of `img.onload()` function `alert(3)` fired before `alert(2)`.

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
var file, img;
if ((file = this.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();
    alert(1)
    img.onload = function() {
         alert(2)
    };
    alert(3)
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mooki/4N6D9/2457/)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Using your current logic, no. The `onload()` is effectively asynchronous. If you need `alert(3)` to appear after `alert(2)`, put it in the onload handler after the `alert(2)`

Comment: Where is the problem , this is fine ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for image to be loaded before going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645143/wait-for-image-to-be-loaded-before-going-on)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Promise.

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

const asyncOnload = img =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    img.onload = () => resolve(alert(2))
    img.onerror = () => reject()
  })

$("#file").change(function(e) {
  var file, img;
  if ((file = this.files[0])) {
      img = new Image();
      alert(1)

      asyncOnload(img).then(() => alert(3))

      img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
});
```

[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/4N6D9/2466/)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to put the third alert in the onload callback?

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        alert(1);
        img.onload = function() {
            alert(2);
            alert(3);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add function to call back. snippet example:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#file").change(function(e) {
var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
      img = new Image();
      alert(1);
      img.onload = function() {
          alert(2);
          call();
      };
      img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
   }
});

function call(){
    alert(3);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is multiple solutions for your problem. The first obvious one is to call your alert in the `img.onload` function, like this:

```
img.onload = () => {
   alert(2)
   alert(3)
}
```

Or, you can simply use the setTimeout function, but it’s more “risky” with slow connection. Hope I fixed your problem .